# How prove $-\sqrt{2}\log(\cos x)\leq\sqrt{x\tan x-\sin^{2}x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

How prove that     $-\sqrt{2}\log(\cos x)\leq\sqrt{x\tan x-\sin^{2}x}$ for all $x\in\left [ 0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$?

Comment: I do not know how to even begin

Comment: Use the derivative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(x)=-\sqrt{2}\log\cos x$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{x \tan x-\sin^2 x}$. Since $f(0)=g(0)=0$, it is sufficient to show that $f'-g'\leq 0$ over $(0,\pi/2)$. This ultimately boils down to proving:
$$4x-\sin(4x)-4\sqrt{2}\sin(2x)\sqrt{x\tan x-\sin^2 x}\geq 0.\tag{1}$$
or the equivalent:
$$(4x-4\sin(2x)+\sin(4x))^2\geq 0,\tag{2}$$
that is trivial.